# C# UDP сокет - работа в интернет

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, udp

Здравствуйте!
Хочу написать клиент сервер на C# используя UDP

Не пойму - 
Если у клиента и сервера IP динамические (сотовая связь), то как происходит доставка? 
Я хочу использовать широковещательную рассылку (чтобы не заморачиваться с портами и адресами, потому что изначально неизвестен IP для обеих сторон)

Курил курил - не пойму - как это работает, пробовал связку для TCP сокета (примеров полно), работает , но там надо указать адрес сервера... А его нет. 
Смысл - запустить программу клиента , которые периодически отправляет сообщение на сервер, и при успешном получении ответа  - отправляет нужные данные.
А программа сервер - работает также только наоборот. Ждет входящего , если пришло делает ответ и ждет файла.

Как идентифицировать их? Без привязки к чему то.

Интересно - без точки не возможно это....

А можно ли тогда указать какой нибудь адрес (от балды) к примеру 125,125,125,125
и конектиться к нему ?

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что в современных мобильных сетях вот так просто разрешат входящие соединения. Устройства почти наверняка за NAT-ом, глобального адреса у них нет, и делать персонально для вас дырку в файерволе никто не будет. Поэтому наиболее реалистичной выглядит схема с центральным ретранслятором и TCP соединениями. Можно пофантазировать о DHT и P2P подключениях, но в условиях динамических адресов, NAT и файерволов это утопия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без статичной точки никак. Нужен сервер к которому будут подсоединятся оба клиента и общаться через него. Либо костыльные решения, но они так или иначе будут использовать хоть что-нибудь статичное.